# What is the English word with the greatest number of consecutive repeated letters?

Tags: word

Example:

- one repeated letter - bitter
- two consecutive repeated letters - bassoon
- three consecutive repeated letters - bookkeeper

I've tried to find a four-times-repeated example but failed.

(Question edited: was 
“Is there an English word with four consecutive repeated letters?”)

Comment: The website [A Collection of Word Oddities and Trivia](http://jeff560.tripod.com/words.html) is great for this sort of thing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended questions are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles). The definition of a "word" is up for debate and there's no way to "prove" your word has the greatest number of consecutive repeats due to that.

Answer (score 36):

The word list on my Mac has one:

```
$ grep '\(.\)\1\(.\)\2\(.\)\3\(.\)\4' /usr/share/dict/words
subbookkeeper
```

Comment: Or bookkeeperess :)

Comment: According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/t52.html) "FAQ" (I really doubt it's asked that frequently) it's the only one.

Comment: @Mynamite That's not an example. The repetitions aren't consecutive.

Comment: Ah very true, I wasn't reading the consecutive bit. Even more importantly, it's not a real word.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It's probably a common trivia question.

Comment: Has it found a place in the OED yet?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It's entered into pop culture just like "antidisestablishmentarianism" as the longest word has (although I don't think it's the longest word anymore). As Barmar said, it's a common trivia question, and I recall a kids' story (I think it might have been Encyclopedia Brown) that used the fact as a plot point.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolem & Barmar. Obviously I lead a sheltered life.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Also, "frequently" in FAQ should not generally be interpreted literally. Often the questions in an FAQ are not actually asked frequently, but just information that you want the readers to know. It's a generalization, and a shorthand way of saying "Important facts".

Comment: @SpehroPefhany A childhood without Encyclopedia Brown is no childhood at all!

Comment: @Nicole: I think "antidisestablishmentarianism" may still be the longest _non-technical_ word out there (not counting proper nouns or words specifically coined for the purpose of being very long). "pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis" has it beat by a wide margin, but even in technical arenas, it's mostly used just as an example of a really long word...

Comment: onelook.com lists this in Urban Dictionary only. Are we sure this is a recognised word?

Comment: I recall subbookkeeper from a Martin Gardner book about 40-50 years ago (in my student time IIRC, and I'm 67 now). Maybe somebody still has it on their shelf.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman what about hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliaphobia?

Comment: @Saiid That word scares me :)

Comment: @Barmar xD I assume you know what it means

Comment: @Saiid - I believe that would fall squarely under "words specifically coined for the purpose of being very long"..

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I wouldn't think so, but ehh

Answer (score 36):

Yellowwooddoor - a door made out of yellowwood (acknowledged as a real Scrabble word). It even has an extra double letter (ll) though it's not consecutive.

(I can't believe how much time I just spent thinking about this. Time to get a life.)

Comment: And "yellowwood door reeffecting" (that is, "putting a yellowwood door into proper working order") has seven consecutive two-letter pairs.

Comment: Or figure out how to charge for billable hours.

Comment: Yeah, right. I smell BBSS... :) Show us the word in a dictionary or Scrabble word list and then I'll upvote you.

Comment: Sorry, according to the online official scrabble dictionary, 'yellowwood' is, but 'yellowwooddoor' is not.

Comment: "Yellowwooddoor" is definitely not listed as a valid Scrabble word. I could not find **any** online dictionary that thinks this is a real word. Provide a reference, please?

Answer (score 18):

Some people raise raccoons for their pelts. A raccoon's home is called a nook. The person who cleans and tidies up the raccoonnooks is called the raccoonnookkeeper.  Real word!

Answer (score 12):

Binnéessiippeele has 6 consecutive pairs and is the name of the "River Crow" tribe of native Americans.

Comment: Hi there! I like your word (wow, I have never seen a word with so many consecutive pairs of letters!), however, the original poster asked specifically for English words, so this answer is not really valid. Good work, though!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this counts, but I have a friend whose last name is Aassekoopannessyttoodde, which has 8 double letters.

Comment: Looking closely, I think the longest run of double letters here is 3 ("ttoodd"), so this does not count. There's a lot of doubles, but they're not connected.